# Shutdown does not power off computer?

Tags: power-management, shutdown, hp, fan

When I shutdown my computer, the fans still run. If I return on, the fans stop. 
I have already tried to change grub but It still doesn't work normally.

Comment: try to shutdown from the command line and see what happens.. and how to you do that?  Not sure what distro.. Google has many options for this.. but in Gnome.. you type this  gnome-session-quit --power-off --force --no-prompt

Comment: I have tried to change" GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" by GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=" quiet splash acpi=force" but it still doesn't work, I shutdown again and the fans still run

Comment: WinEunuuchs2Unix: you mean I should update new version for ubuntu

Comment: Can you `edit` your question and put in your HP model and Ubuntu version (14.04 may power off where 16.04 wont),?

Comment: @Thanh I'm not suggesting upgrading anything. I'm trying to find out what you have now to narrow down searches for solutions.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix yes, I have tried some solutions, but it was ineffective

Comment: @Thanh have you tried`systemctl poweroff -i` yet?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix not yet, I have tried sudo -i

Comment: After that, I changed  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

Comment: This command halts the system after shutdown. Try simply: sudo shutdown -h now

Comment: @Software_Programineer Thank you, I tried it but the fan still run after shutdowning

Comment: Just try to shut down from terminal and not grub.  See what happens.  Keep it simple to rule out problems.

Comment: @BhikkhuSubhuti Thank you for your comment. I tried it and nothing changed.

Comment: You've got to get it to work with command line first before even bothering with grub (as far as I know)  seems like you have a hardware problem.  You do not mention your flavor or version of ubuntu.  Try another flavor or update.  Does windows do this.  Did this do this before.  Is this from a new install.?  You do not give proper information for people to help you.

Comment: @BhikkhuSubhuti As I said before, I have tried to shutdown by the command, used the grub command. After that, I update and install the sorfware, but it has not changed anymore. The problem what I gave before is that the fans still run when I shutdown the computer.

Comment: You have yet to reveal your version number and flavor.  There are various sudo commands to shut down your computer.  You should update all of the commands that you have tried in your post. There are also power management commands too.  YOu should look there.

Comment: Try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/778001/ubuntu-16-04-wont-shutdown and read about sys md in the comment.. not sure what that is.

Comment: Curious about your hardware setup and the fan that will not stop. Is the fan that stays on the CPU fan? Is it a case fan? Is the fan connected to the motherboard or just to molex connectors from the PSU? Or how is that fan (the one that will not shut off) connected and powered? Does it have any physical buttons or switches on the fan itself? Does this happen with any other OS? and most importantly.... Which OS are you actually using?

Comment: I use the ubuntu version 14.04. I have updated the programming  and command. I openned hardware and fan to see the devices.